# add a option to the flash player when you right click

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash

I would like to add a option to flash context menu of  the adobe player . how can i do this ?

Comment: What do you mean by option? Would you like to add a menu element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add items to the context menu.  Check out the [ContextMenu](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html) class and [related examples](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html#includeExamplesSummary).

Here is [a blog post](http://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2008/12/2/Accessing-the-Right-Click-Menu-in-Flex) I wrote on the subject; which adds a context menu to an image.  This is the source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="onCreationComplete()" width="100%" height="100%" viewSourceURL="srcview/index.html">
    <mx:Image width="100%" height="100%" source="assets/spacer.jpg" alpha="0" maintainAspectRatio="false" id="ImageTest" />

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            public function onCreationComplete():void{
                var menuItem:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("Version 1");
//                menuItem.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT,doStuff);

                var customContextMenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();

                //hide the Flash menu
//                customContextMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
                customContextMenu.customItems.push(menuItem);

                ImageTest.contextMenu = customContextMenu;
            }

            private function doStuff(e:Event):void{
                trace('stuff');
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: can i add the menu item to any flash video using this code ? how can i insert this code into action script code of flash ? For eg : can i insert this code into youtube.com flash ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use this code on a video object.  And the ActionScript portions of the code you should be able to use in flash.  It is "compile time" code; so you won't be able to add it to the Youtube video player, but if you're using Youtube APIs to play YouTube videos in your own application, then you should be able to add the context menu to it.

Comment: Then how recording plugins like real players can customize the context menu for all flash videos ?

Comment: @user1668527 I don't know which plugin you're referring to.  RealPlayer ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RealPlayer ) is not Flash Based